# I dropped brigthness to 0 in compizconfig. How to recover

Tags: compiz, brightness

I was testing the brightness, opacity and saturation plugin and dropped the brigthness to 0, now without having apply (but pressed ESC), I can´t control my Ubuntu anymore (all windows are black). How can I recover from this?

Comment: Switch to a TTY (Ctrl-Alt-F1), maybe try moving `~/.config/compiz-1` or `~/.config/ccm` somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to go to TTY mode, type your user name and password. Then run following command to restore compiz setting.

```
rm  -rf ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1
```

To access GUI again, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, I actually edited the file you said with nano, because even if it is binary, there are some words. One of the words were `type=any` near brightness word, so I changed it to `dany` and when I went back to tty7, it fixed.

Comment: Glad it got fixed :D

Comment: By the way, the config file was  `~/.config/dconf/user` I thought I read this file name here lol